# Relation between representations and roots, weights

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-algebras

Given a Lie Group (take for example the classical ones) we know that there are certain representations for it. For example in $SU(N)$ we can have an adjoint, fundamental, symmetric and antisymmetric representations.

On the other hand we can study the associated Lie Algebra and the root system, weight and root lattices etc (For example take the Appendix C of [this](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf)). What's the relation between the aforementioned representations and the classification of the Algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by decomposition on the root system?

Comment: For example the root system listed in the appendix C of: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a relation between the representations and the classification. One is associated to a specific Lie algebra, while the other tells you what Lie algebras are possible. These are very different things. Do you mean what one can say about the representations once one knows the associated root system?

Comment: Yes, exactly, once that the associated root system is known what can be said about the representations? In particular how can I tell properties such as anti symmetry or such...